# Java SFTP Mule Library Issue : ClassDef Not found

Tags: java, maven, mule, sftp

I am working on a Java utility that gets files from HDFS to a remote machine. I have some issues in the SFTP library import. I have included org mule transport and the related libraries in the POM and after doing mvn install I can see that the Classes are available in the dependency Path. However when I execute the class I get the error message as follow:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpClient
    at xxxx.yyyyyy.sftpFileTransfer.main(sftpFileTransfer.java:17)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpATTRS;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient;



public class sftpFileTransfer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("This is for testing");
    SftpClient sftpCli = new SftpClient("abcdef");
    sftpCli.login("karthick_kb","/home/karthick/.ssh/id_rsa", null);
    sftpCli.changeWorkingDirectory("/tmp/");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    FSDataInputStream fsdisPath = null;
    String filePath = null;
    filePath = "/a/b/c/d/e/f/1.dat.gz";
    Path inputPath = new Path(filePath);
    fsdisPath = fs.open(inputPath);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fsdisPath);
    sftpCli.storeFile(inputPath.getName(), bis);
    fsdisPath.close();

}
}
```

The maven dependencies are as follows

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
<version>0.1.54</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mule</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-transport-sftp</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

I am able to see the required SFTP Classes in the maven dependencies What could I be missing.. Any information would be great

[image]

Comment: Might be a version issue.  Believe the JVM.  Look in all your JARs to see if the class org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpClient is there.  If it's not, look at other versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-sftp

Comment: I am able to see those classes in the maven dependencies -> mule-transport-sftp-3.4.0 jar ->SftpClient.class. So Classes are available as part of the package.

Comment: I see them in Maven dependencies too, but that does not guarantee that the missing class is in the JAR.  Open the JAR and find it.  If it's in the JAR, then check your package and make sure it's actually in the package.  The JVM is smarter than you are.  If it can't find it, you have to assume that it is not available.

Comment: I have added the screen shot for your reference.I am able to see the class in the JAR file.

Comment: Next step: The package you're deploying.  Do you see that JAR in the package?

Comment: Do you mean the final Jar I am deploying. I just tried to use jar tvf test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and I dont see any other dependent jars in the list. I am just in the learning phase of java. Please correct me if I am wrong and suggest me how else to find it.

Comment: You should open it with WinZip or something like that.  Did you create your deployable JAR using the Maven Shade plugin?  If not, that would explain it.  The JAR is not available at runtime.

Comment: No chat.  I'm a volunteer.

Comment: I did a winzip extract and I dont any see anyother classes avaible in extracted folder. How to add the dependent jars in runtime? I did a mvn clean install in the  project path

Comment: I told you: Learn how to use the Maven Shade plugin to create a FAT JAR with all the dependencies inside.

Comment: Is your application a standard Java application or a Mule application?